# HTTP500 returned when OAuth token introspection results in HTTP400 in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

My ResourceServer is configured as follows:

```
http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::opaqueToken)
    .authorizeRequests();
```

I configured a CustomTokenIntrospector like this:

```
public class CustomAuthoritiesOpaqueTokenIntrospector implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector {
    private OpaqueTokenIntrospector delegate =
            new NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector("https://idp.example.org/introspect", "client", "secret");

    public OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal introspect(String token) {
        OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = this.delegate.introspect(token);
        return new DefaultOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(
                principal.getName(), principal.getAttributes(), extractAuthorities(principal));
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal) {
        List<String> scopes = principal.getAttribute(OAuth2IntrospectionClaimNames.SCOPE);
        return scopes.stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

If `this.delegate.introspect(token)` is called with an *invalid token*, a HTTP400 response is received from the AuthorisationServer. The ResourceServer then sends a HTTP500 response to the user. How can I change this response to the original HTTP400?
I tried @ExceptionHandler which doesn't get called in this case.

```
    @ExceptionHandler({AuthenticationServiceException.class, OAuth2IntrospectionException.class, HttpClientErrorException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAuthenticationServiceExceptionException(
        final RuntimeException e,
        WebRequest request
    ) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(e, e.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }
```